# XML Character <Unicode: 0xc> was found in the element content of the document

Tags: java, xml, pdf, netbeans

I am generating pdf from a SQL query on a java app.
I have 4M pdf to print.

On the 15092th pdf.
I am encountering this error

```
Invalid xml character (unicode 0xc) was found in the element content of the document
```

I tried to replace as what other blogs are saying.

```
    html = html.replaceAll("\000"," ");
    html = html.replaceAll("/\u000c+/g", "");
```

I don't know which is which I just placed them to my html.

Anyone with an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: None of them is correct Java code. And what do you mean with “I just placed them to my html”?

Comment: Hi. I mean XML.. i just used html as a variable. So what should I do to escape all unicode characters in xml?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do a replacement. I describe them a bit more in detail as I think it’s more important to understand them instead of just copying code.

1. A simple character-by-character replacement. This works in your case as you just want to replace occurrences of a certain character. Since your character is a control character you cannot (usually) insert it directly but through one of the following ways:

   - Unicode reference: `html=html.replace('\u000c', ' '); // hexadecimal value == 0xc`
   - Octal reference: `html=html.replace('\14', ' '); // 0xc == 014`
   - By its meaning:  `html=html.replace('\f', ' '); // character 0xc is a form-feed`

   Unicode references are a bit tricky as they are processed before the Java parser so they don’t work with characters having a special meaning to the Java language. But with a form-feed it works.
2. Using regular expressions. This is an over-sized solution to this task but it works as performing exact matching of single characters is a valid subset of regular expression syntax. So you can use all of the above variants and construct a regular expression based solution by replacing the method name with `replaceAll` and change the parameters to strings, e.g. `html=html.replaceAll("\14", " ");`
   In this case the character reference is still generated by the compiler and has no special meaning to the regular expression engine.
   When using the regular expression engine actively you have similar choices to the character references of the Java language:

   - Unicode reference: `html=html.replaceAll("\\u000c", " ");`
   - Hexadecimal reference: `html=html.replaceAll("\\x0c", " "); // no Java equivalent`
   - Octal reference: `html=html.replaceAll("\\014", " "); // note the subtle difference`
   - By its meaning:  `html=html.replaceAll("\\f", " ");`

The difference is that these sequences insert a backslash at Java language level (via *double-backslash*) forming a regular expression that is processed by the regular expression engine. Therefore the Unicode reference works for all characters here.
The entire syntax is described here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

But as already said for your task the simple character matching is enough.

So why do your examples not work?

`html = html.replaceAll("\000"," ");`
The sequence `\0` is interpreted as a reference to control character 0x0 and it’s followed by two zeros. So it attempts to find sequences of control character `NUL` followed by two zeros.

`html = html.replaceAll("/\u000c+/g", "");`
This sequence consists of the characters `'/'` `'\f'` (defined via correct unicode sequence) `'+'` `'/'` `'g'`. Only the plus sign has special meaning in regular expressions in Java. It means “at least one” and “as much as can be found”. So this code looks for sequences of your character 0xc but only if they are framed by slashes and followed by a `'g'`.